# No exception in continuous webjob when you regenerate the service bus root manager sas key

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk, azure-servicebus-topics

I have webjob with service bus trigger. Things works fine. I was expecting a running webjob to throw exception when I regenerate the primary key which is used to create the service bus config during the start up of webjob.

Basically I do not want my webjob to run continuously if a service connection string is made invalid post running. The problem here is, webjob continuously runs but it does not respond or methods in functions with the service bus trigger attribute does not get invoked for any new messages in queue or topic post 20 minutes regenerating the service bus key. 
When a storage or dashboard connection string become invalid, it throws the error. Why is servicebus thing not having the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you either use [OnMessage API](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/azure-service-bus-onmessage-api) (old client) or [register a handler](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/tree/master/samples/DotNet/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/BasicSendReceiveUsingQueueClient) (new client). If you do so, run for a while and regenerate Shared Access Key, then the underlying connection is becoming a zombie, but not detected and no exception is thrown.

This looks like a bug.
Raised issues for both the [new](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/issues/357) and the [old](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues/105) clients.

Comment: Any idea when it will be fixed? We need to rely on this exception to get the new servicebus key from the vault and start the webjob again when we regenerate the service bus connection key.

Comment: I'd suggest to raise that in the issues and track the progress there.